# heapq.merge: after merge the result of merge, the original merge is empty

Tags: python, heapq

First I created two results of a & b by using `heapq.merge`, but after `merge`ing a&b, I found the list of a is empty.

```
>>> a=merge([1,2],[3,4])
>>> b=merge([4,5],[6,7])
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> merge(a,b)
<generator object merge at 0x365c370>
>>> list(a)
[]
>>>
```

The final result of `list(a)` is empty, why does `merge(a,b)` change a?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation (and the output on `merge(a,b)` in your example) indicates, the result of `merge` is an iterator. Iterators can only be consumed once, you can't reset or rewind them, and even if you could, your code doesn't do it. (Of course you can have several independent iterators for a given collection, at least if the collection supports it).

The first two `merge` calls return generators, the third call consumes those generators, and hence `a` and `b` are exhausted afterwards. (Actually, `list(a)` consumes `a` first, so in that snippet `merge(a, b)` will only see the items of `b`, but the idea is the same.) It doesn't *mean* to, and if you pass e.g. a list it won't be changed. But consuming an iterator means mutating it.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a=heapq.merge([1,2],[3,4])
>>> b = heapq.merge([4,5], [6,7])
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> heapq.merge(a,b)
<generator object merge at 0x7f083da50f50>
>>> list(a)
[]
>>> list(b)
[4, 5, 6, 7] // before you consume the iterator of b
>>> list(b)
[]   // after you consume the iterator of b
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` is not a list but an iterator. If you use it once, you cannot iterate with it a second time. This has nothing to do with `merge`; you see the same effect here:

```
>>> a=merge([1,2],[3,4])
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(a)            
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `heapq.merge` is an iterator. When you apply `list` to an iterator, it is consumed. An iterator is good for one pass over the set of values. So the second time `list(a)` is called, the result is empty.